Why Clay Strip Tool destroy my mesh in sculpt mode?
I think I had disabled autosmooth in Clay Strip tool, and already remesh my mesh using Remesh tool in sculpt mode, but when I use the tool, it destroy my mesh instead of making clay strip on it 
What happened here? How I can fix this?


Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the edit link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "this","issue with" or "question about". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is.

See "What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?""

I reckon just from the screenshot that your normal is the wrong way around on your model, try flipping it outwards and see if that helps.

@NascentSpace I already tried to flip the normals and use the clay strip tool brush on one side of the object, but it substract the other side

I don't know why Blender does this sometimes but you can prevent it when you tick the Advanced > [X] Front Faces Only checkbox in the brush settings.

@Blunder it work..  but with some side effects, when I brush the object's face in wider area, it looks normal. But when I brush it over the narrow one, it become stretched almost like torn apart between faces
